# how to contact a single peer in a wcf p2p cloud?

Tags: .net, wcf, p2p

I'm using WCF to let multiple peers connect to each other using the NetPeerTcpBinding.

Is there a way to contact a single peer in this mesh?

Preferably I would like to contact this peer transparently, so that the receiver simply continues to listen to the channel it always has, while the sender jumps through some hoops to deliver the message to the receiver only.

Answer (score 1):

WCF peer-to-peer does not have a built-in way to target an individual node in the mesh, but Microsoft has provided some recommendations on how to get it done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733062.aspx